# Django dumpdata returns empty array when models are in a version subdirectory

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a Django Rest Framework app where I have separated my models/serializers/views into separate directories (instead of in models.py, serializers.py, etc) and moved those directories into a v1 directory.

When I try to run `./manage.py dumpdata api` I get an empty array as response.

`./manage.py dumpdata` will dump out the Django system tables, but none of my model tables.

Here's an example:

```
- api/
-- __init__.py
-- v1/
--- router.py
--- __init__.py
--- models/
---- __init__.py
---- thingy.py
--- serializers/
---- __init__.py
---- thingy.py
--- views/
---- __init__.py
---- thingy.py

- project/
-- urls.py
-- settings.py
-- wsgi.py
-- __init__.py
```

The `__init__.py` file inside each object directory (e.g. models) includes the class from each file:

```
from .thingy import Thingy
```

The `router.py` file inside `api/` looks like this:

```
from rest_framework import routers
from . import views

router = routers.DefaultRouter(trailing_slash=False)
router.register(r'thingies', views.ThingyViewSet)

api_urlpatterns = router.urls
```

And `urls.py` inside `project/` looks like this:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from api.v1.router import api_urlpatterns as api_v1

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^api/v1/', include(api_v1)),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
]
```

Comment: Do you have your application in INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: I do, as "api". In api/apps.py, I have the `name` attribute of my ApiConfig as "api" as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out the issue. While I had the files in each v1 folder (models, serializers, views) included in their respective `__init__.py` files, the manager was still expecting a `models` module in the base of the `api` directory. I added a `models.py` file and included each of the models under `api.v1.models` and now it appears to be finding my models.

Thanks for looking!